# What does "$" mean in Python?

Tags: python, syntax

I am studying on a page : https://docs.python.org/3.7/howto/argparse.html#id1

There are many "$" in the page, For example:  `$ ls, $ python3 prog.py` ....

What is it? I am looking for information about it, but I can get nothing.

Also I typed in my Jupyter Notebook, but it says it is not valid.
Is it something like a "situation"??

I cannot find any information about $. Here too

Comment: Nothing. That page is about using the _command line_, $ is a common prompt for e.g. bash. The examples using it are **not** Python, they're showing the resulting CLI.

Comment: @jonrsharpe not for python code? OMG.... thank you I did really waste my time on it T_T

Comment: The $ at the beginning of the line indicates that it is a shell command. If you are interested you can read more about it [here](https://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/282/prompt-in-command-line-instructions)

Answer (score 1):

$ is used to indicate that the documentation text is not python code, but rather a shell command being run in the command line of the computer running your code. ($ is also not python specific, this is standard notation to indicate a shell command).

In jupyter notebook, you don't have direct access to the shell, but you can prefix a line with "!" to indicate that you want to run that line in the shell rather than the python interpreter. For example

```py
!ls
!python3 prog.py
print("Hello World") #regular python code
```

Comment: Well if I use $ in Python IDLE, then $ works??

Comment: No, you don't use $ anywhere, it's just an indicator that the text coming after the $ is a shell command. Similarly, the python IDLE uses ">>>" to indicate that you are typing in the IDLE.

Answer (score 1):

It's Shell prompt in Linux indicating the user account type you are logged in to.

- Dollar sign ( $ ) means you are a normal user.
- hash ( # ) means you are the system administrator (root).
- In the C shell, the prompt ends with a percentage sign ( % ).